# Add Icons to WooCommerce Product on Overview Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am working with Wordpress Elementor and WooCommerce. Maybe there is some sort of a Plugin or something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these images by customizing the woocommerce in your theme.
You can edit the shop page template. Go to the directory
'**plugins\woocommerce\templates**' then edit this file **content-product.php**
[content-product-file-template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J6n5.png)

Comment: So you mean with ACF and adding images via Backend?

Comment: Yes, you can fetch the data of ACF field images within the product loop.